# Symfony 2.3.5 Fatal error: Class 'ResourceBundle' not found on Server

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using NameCheap host server with PHP Version 5.3.27 and no intl extension installed.

Although I try to put this lines in `php.ini` it still not work.

```
[PHP]
detect_unicode = off
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
date.timezone=Europe/Berlin
short_open_tag = off
magic_quotes_gpc = off
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so

extension=intl.so
extension=php_intl.dll

[intl]
intl.default_locale = en_utf8
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

So, when I execute my web, I have this issue:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'ResourceBundle' not found in /home/esdrhazc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/ResourceBundle/Reader/BinaryBundleReader.php line 31
```

To avoid this problem I added next lines to `autoload.php`

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once  __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');

$loader->registerPrefixFallbacks(
    array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs')
);

}

$loader->add('Gestor', __DIR__.'/../src');

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

What more can I do? Its strange because if i navigate inside host, the previous path doesn't exist, the corrects are:

```
/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/stubs
```

but I try to change it and it still doesn't work. And, I can't find `functions.php`.

In case there isn't a solution, which host can I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you should consult your NameCheap about enabling `intl` extension, that's the only thing that solves this problem (I had the same issue, though not on NameCheap). ˙intl` is needed for validators in Symfony. However, your last question about choosing a hosting company would result in off topic answers here. OFF: I usually use GoDaddy with much satisfaction

Answer (score 0):

As other people have suggested, you need `intl` extension. You have two options the first one is to use native `c` `intl` extension. Installation will depend on your operating system. Second option is to use symfony `intl` extension written in `php`. To install `php` extension just add

```
"symfony/intl": "2.5.6"
```

to the `require` section in your `composer.json` file. If the native `intl` extension is not available `sf2` will failover to use `php` version instead. You can read more: [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/intl.html)